# Perspective projection inverting x axis (glm::perspective)

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math, perspectivecamera, projection-matrix

When I use a perspective projection in OpenGL, my X axis gets inverted as seen in the image below. The code below might not be valid because I changed it a lot in order to make it less obscure. It might not work, so just keep that in mind. Here is the code and vertices:

```
 typedef struct{
   float x;
   float y;
   float z;
 } vertex_t;

  glm::vec3 position = glm::vec3(0, 0, 0);
  glm::vec3 look_at = glm::vec3(0, 0, 1);

  glm::mat4 projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(45.0f, (float)800 / (float)600, 0.1f, 100.f); 
  glm::mat4 modelMatrix = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f));
  glm::mat4 viewMatrix = glm::lookAt(
    position, 
    look_at,
    glm::vec3(0, 1, 0) 
  );

  vertex_t data[3] = {
    {-0.5,  0.5, -0.5f},
    { 0.5,  0.5, -0.5f},
    {-0.5, -0.5, -0.5f},
  };

  unsigned int indices[3] = {
    0, 1, 2
  };

 glm::mat4 mvp = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix; //This is passed in as the uniform u_MVP later
```

This is the vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;

uniform mat4 u_MVP;

void main(){
  gl_Position = u_MVP * position;
}
```

And this is the output. As you can see, it doesn't match the vertices provided.
[image]

If you need the entire code, or if you want me to provide the original version, please let me know. Thanks!

**UPDATE**: I've tried a negative Z axis, and it hasn't worked. Heres the code:

```
  position = glm::vec3(0, 0, 0);
  look_at = glm::vec3(0, 0, -1);

  
  glm::mat4 projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(45.0f, (float)800 / (float)600, 0.1f, 100.f); 
  glm::mat4 modelMatrix = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f));
  viewMatrix = glm::lookAt(
    position,
    look_at, 
    glm::vec3(0, 1, 0)  // Tilt/rotation (unclear) set y to -1 for upside down view
  );
```

Comment: I think your problem might be related to your camera rather than your projection matrix. What's happening is that you're looking at it from behind, hence it seems as if x is inverted. Remember that OpenGL uses a right-handed coord-system, meaning that the z-axis points out of the screen towards you. Imagine your triangle on the screen. You translate it by 5 (~5 steps out of the screen), and your camera (in the screen) looks in that direction. Hence the output. What you want is the model moved by -5 and the camera looking in the negative direction.

Comment: @Beko thanks! could you post this as an answer?

Comment: Np, Rabbid has already answered it, so no need.

Comment: @Beko You are right. We spotted out the same issue (almost at the same time). Don't post comments, but post answers. Actually your comment is an answer.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Yes pretty much simultaneously. I'll keep that in mind (:

Comment: @Beko I'm getting a black screen, the triangle isn't appearing. But the higher the number on the Z-Axis is, the further away the triangle is getting, suggesting that its a left-handed system. What's wrong?

Comment: I don't know, looks fine to me. In your shader you have your `position` as `vec4`, may be worth checking out. Make it a `vec3` in the shader and change the calc to `u_MVP * vec4(position, 1.0)` and see if that changes anything. Edit: and what you say has nothing to do with LHS/RHS. The difference is just the direction in which the z-axis points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The x-axis doesn't get inverted because of the projection matrix, but it get's inverted because of the view matrix.

> ```cpp
> glm::vec3 position = glm::vec3(0, 0, 0);
> glm::vec3 look_at = glm::vec3(0, 0, 1);
> glm::mat4 viewMatrix = glm::lookAt(position, look_at, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
> ```

The view space is a [Right-handed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-hand_rule) system, where the X-axis points to the right and the Y-axis points up. The Z-axis points out of the view (Note in a right hand system the Z-Axis is the cross product of the X-Axis and the Y-Axis).

Hence you look at the triangle from the back.

Change the model matrix and the view matrix. Shift the triangle along the negative Z axis. Define a line of sight pointing in the negative z-direction:

```cpp
glm::mat4 modelMatrix = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f));

glm::vec3 position = glm::vec3(0, 0, 0);
glm::vec3 look_at = glm::vec3(0, 0, -1);
glm::mat4 viewMatrix = glm::lookAt(position, look_at, glm::vec3(0, 1, 0));
```

---

The distances to the near and far plane have to be positive values and th unit of the angle for [`glm::perspective`](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.9/api/a00243.html#ga747c8cf99458663dd7ad1bb3a2f07787) is [radiant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian):

```
0 < near < far
```

<s>`glm::mat4 projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(45.0f, (float)800 / (float)600, -0.1f, -100.f);`</s>

```cpp
glm::mat4 projectionMatrix = glm::perspective(
    glm::radians(45.0f), 800.0f/600.0f, 0.1f, 100.f);
```

Comment: I'm getting a black screen, the triangle isn't appearing. But the higher the number on the Z-Axis is, the further away the triangle is getting, suggesting that its a left-handed system. What's wrong?

Comment: changed both of them, when the z position is negative, I cannot see anything.

Comment: i've added  the code, could you take a look?

Comment: I tried it with positive values, same thing

Comment: It doesnt work for me. Ive narrowed down the problem to this line: ```look_at = glm::vec3(0, 0, -1);```. When this looks at z=1, everything is fine (including when the modelMatrix is at -5 z) but when its at negative 1, I cannot see anything

Comment: Still doens't work. Its almost like I cant look at the negative z axis

Comment: I've figured out something else: If the position of the camera (on the Z axis) is larger than the look_at position (for the Z axis) the screen turns black

Comment: Could you add your working code to the answer? Ill figure out the rest by myself

Comment: @Serket I've copied the "UPDATE" code from your question. Then I changed  `45.0f,` to `glm::radians(45.0f)` and it works fine for me.

Comment: It doenst work, could you add your working code and Ill do the rest

Comment: @Serket Which working code? I've put your matrix setup to an arbitrary example on my local drive. Anyway https://pastebin.com/MNp0TQZS. Required files can be found at https://github.com/Rabbid76/graphics-snippets/tree/master/example/cpp/_util/include/gl

Comment: Thanks I’ll let you know when I figure out the problem